# 24v to 12v truck cigarette socket wiring

Tags: 24v

Hi guys i have a aerpro 24v to 12v reducer, but it has a positive a negative and an earth wire i need to wire it up so i can plug it in to a 24v truck socket and then have the 12v going to a cigarette female end any ideas on how to go about this? P.s i already have the male cigarette socket. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvfB.jpg)

Comment: did you bother to read the label on the reducer??

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the image, the wires are :

Red 24v supply fused

White 12v output (be good to fit a fuse here as well...)

Black ground / earth

Make sure you get this correct - NOT, as you put "but it has a positive a negative and an earth wire"...

So, for your truck socket you can get male plugs and red wire to the centre pin, black wire to the outside terminals, BUT do check that the socket you use has been wired correctly...